# Writing the SQL CASE statement to update a column based on the value of another column from another table

Tags: sql-server, case

I need to update the values in a Column named "TravelAgencyID2" in "dbo.ReservationStay" based on the values of column "TravelAgencyTypeCode" of "dbo.TravelAgency".

The condition of the update is like this: If TravelAgencyTypeCode in dbo.TravelAgency is NOT EQUAL to 'DMC', then TravelAgencyID2 = TravelAgencyID (from dbo.ReservationStay), ELSE TravelAgencyID2 remains unchanged.

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: You've pretty much written the query in your description. Can you post your effort please?

Comment: I am stuck when the condition depends on a column from another table! I can write the CASE statement when both columns are in the same table but I just can't figure out how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO, you only need to update those rows *WHERE* a condition is met?

```
UPDATE rs
SET rs.TravelAgencyID2 = rs.TravelAgencyID
FROM ReservationStay rs
  INNER JOIN TravelAgency ta on rs.TravelAgencyID2 = ta.ID
WHERE ta.TravelAgencyTypeCode  != 'DMC'
```

This will only update the rows you need, without touching anything else.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't have been able to figure this out as I thought JOIN could not be used in an UPDATE.

Comment: Yes, it's a common cause of confusion when one is learning SQL, so you're not alone :) I'm not really sure which parts of the UPDATE ..FROM syntax are standard, and which SQL Server specific, but it gets the job done...